# Angular: correct alternate coloring of rows with ngIf

Tags: css, angular

I am showing a table with Angular. The data for that is in a list.

My table should have alternating colors. I use CSS nth-child for that.

```
tr:nth-child(even)
{
  background: white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)
{
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Now I added a filter for the table. Only rows that match a special criteria should be displayed.

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of data">
   <ng-container *ngIf="filtermatch (d)">
     <td>{{ d.text }}</td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```

But now the correct alternating coloring only happens if NO filter is present. If I use a filter I think the coloring is made up on the complete data and not the filtered.

Is there beside

- color manually by counting the rows
- filter before and use the filterd data in the table

another way that would work for me?

I would like to filter with ngIf and use CSS-nth-child.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this

Component:

```
color = 0;
```

Template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of data; let i=index;">
   <ng-container *ngIf="filtermatch(d)">
     <td [ngClass]="color=!color ? 'even' : 'odd'">{{ d.text }}</td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```